# Email integration in using Spring MVC

Tags: spring

Iam using the framework Spring mvc and I need to login and signup using email id.and send mail to particular mail id .Now Iam using Spring security for login and username is using for signup and login and I need to change to Email ID

Could you please help anyone

Answer (score 0):

You can basically add this to your security xml file and configure based on your database.

```
     <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
           <authentication-provider>
                <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" 
                    users-by-username-query="
                        select email_address,password, enabled 
                        from user where email_address=?" 

                    authorities-by-username-query="
                        select u.email_address, ur.authority from user u, authorities ur 
                        where u.user_id = ur.user_id and u.email_address =?  " 
                />                      
           </authentication-provider>
        </authentication-manager>
```